# How can a Minecraft server be restarted daily and gracefully on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting, ubuntu

I've got a (modded) Minecraft server running in a tmux session on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. What might be a good way to get it to shut down gracefully and then relaunch daily at, say, 05:00 in the morning?

So, in the tmux window, I am running a command like the following:

```
while true; do java -Xmx15G -Xms15G -jar forge-1.14.4-28.2.0.jar nogui; sleep 120; done
```

This launches the Minecraft server, and relaunches it after a couple of minutes if it crashes. But in order to optimise performance, I would like the Minecraft server to shut down at, say, 05:00 in the morning gracefully, as it would with the Minecraft server command `/stop`, and then to restart. How might this be done?

Is there some sleep command for the server that could, on launch, cause the server to `/stop` after 24 hours, and then my little loop script restarts it? Is there a way to tell the server to stop when it detects there are no users?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your command line to start the **forge** program even if it's already running, you can add a [check to see if forge is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157779/how-to-determine-whether-a-process-is-running-or-not-and-make-use-it-to-make-a-c) to it.

As per the highest answer there, your code would look like:

```
while true; do 
    if pgrep -f "forge" > /dev/null
    then
        java -Xmx15G -Xms15G -jar forge-1.14.4-28.2.0.jar nogui &
    else 
        echo "Minecraft appears to already be running";
    fi
    sleep 120;
done
```

The `&` will run java asynchronously, allowing more command to run while the server is running. (Insert them in between `fi` and `sleep`). This can be useful to solve your second point:

For your second question, you may perhaps want to check out an [rcon client](https://bukkit.org/threads/admin-rcon-mcrcon-remote-connection-client-for-minecraft-servers.70910/) program. This allows you to access the minecraft command console from within bash and handles all the protocol and security features of the game for you.

You will want to:

1. Read the 'player name' string into a variable.`rcon -u admin -p password list`
2. If the output from above is empty, execute `rcon -u admin -p password stop` to stop the server.

See below:

```
$output=rcon -u admin -p password list
if [ -z "$output" ]; then 
    rcon -u admin -p password stop 
fi
```

One small thing about this:

If you immediately stop the server (run the above in a loop just like your current script) then the last player disconnecting might immediately cause a reset. This may not be what you want: if the last player disconnects due to their internet they may lose their current state. Perhaps it would be a good idea to add a bit of delay: require the check to succeed twice in a row instead.